# How to unpack column contents to new columns determined by cell's value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains information about student grades, test scores, and other metrics. One of the columns contains comma separated text where each comma separated value is the name of a math class and the grade the student achieved in that class. So the dataframe looks as follows:

```
STUDENT_ID    TEST_SCORE_1    TEST_SCORE_2    MATHS
001           85              93              ALGEBRA_B+,GEOMETRY_A-,TRIGONOMETRY_C
002           73              95              ALGEBRA_B,GEOMETRY_B+,CALCULUS_C
```

What I would like is to have columns corresponding to each class, and simply have the cells containing the grade like this:

```
STUDENT_ID    TEST_SCORE_1    TEST_SCORE_2    ALGEBRA    GEOMETRY    TRIGONOMETRY    CALCULUS
001           85              93              B+         A-          C               NaN
002           73              95              B          B+          NaN             C
```

I first tried to do something like this

```
df.merge(df['Maths'].apply(unpack_grades), left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

where unpack_grades is a function that parses through the string of classes and grades and returns a pandas series containing every math course in the catalog as keys with the grades as values (NaN if the student has not taken the class). Here is the beginning of that function:

```
def unpack_grades(x):

    courses = [a.strip() for a in x.split(',')]
```

However, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'
```

If anyone can suggest a fix for my error, or even an alternate approach if there is a more direct way to achieve what I'm after, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression and `pivot` here.

```
u = df.MATHS.str.extractall(r'([a-zA-Z]+)_([A-F][+-]?)').reset_index(1, drop=True)

#               0   1
# 0       ALGEBRA  B+
# 0      GEOMETRY  A-
# 0  TRIGONOMETRY   C
# 1       ALGEBRA   B
# 1      GEOMETRY  B+
# 1      CALCULUS   C

p = u.pivot(columns=0, values=1)

# 0 ALGEBRA CALCULUS GEOMETRY TRIGONOMETRY
# 0      B+      NaN       A-            C
# 1       B        C       B+          NaN

pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :-1], p], axis=1)
```

```
   STUDENT_ID  TEST_SCORE_1  TEST_SCORE_2 ALGEBRA CALCULUS GEOMETRY TRIGONOMETRY
0           1            85            93      B+      NaN       A-            C
1           2            73            95       B        C       B+          NaN
```

---

***Regex Explanation***

```
(                            # capture group 1
  [a-zA-Z]                   # match letters
  +                          # match 1 or more times
)
_                            # match the _ character
(                            # capture group 2
  [A-F]                      # match A-F (possible grades)
  [+-]                       # match either + or -
  ?                          # optional match of the + or -
)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. I did run into an unforeseen issue where a student may have taken a class more than once. This causes "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape" when creating the pivot table. Is there a straightforward way to choose one entry? I'm really only interested in the best grade.

Comment: Use `pivot_table` instead of `pivot`, with `aggfunc='first'`